# how to connect to a liblo TCP OSC server?

Tags: network-programming, osc

I'm using [liblo](https://github.com/radarsat1/liblo) for OSC communication ([lowlevel API](http://liblo.sourceforge.net/docs/group__liblolowlevel.html)) via UDP for some time now and I'm currently trying to switch to TCP. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to use the library for TCP. The [echoserver](https://github.com/radarsat1/liblo/blob/master/examples/example_tcp_echo_server.c) demonstrates how to set up a server. Basically, I do this:

```
_tcpThread = lo_server_thread_new_with_proto( "7000", LO_TCP, errorHandler );
_tcpServer = lo_server_thread_get_server( _tcpThread );
lo_server_thread_start( _tcpThread );

_address = lo_address_new_with_proto( LO_TCP, "127.0.0.1", "7000" );
lo_send_message_from( _address, _tcpServer, "/test", message );
```

Now, how do I create a client that connects to the TCP socket and receives sent OSC packages? Documentation and sample code leaves me scratching my head. Create a second server on client side? How do I tell it where to connect to?

---

EDIT: okay, I figured out now that `lo_send_message_from` actually wants the target address as a first argument. From this I infer that I would have to iterate through all connected clients and sent to the respective sockets. Question remains, who do I connect a client to the server? Second question arises, how do I know what clients are connected that I could send my packages to?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out in the meantime and I'm again that guy answering his own question, but chances are it's of use to someone:

Seems like the cause of confusion was that in OSC the term "server" refers to the peer *getting data sent to* and "client" to the peer *providing the data*, not vice versa. Once you know that, everything is pretty easy when looking at the echoserver sample I mentioned in the question: you open a "server" socket by `lo_server_thread_new_with_proto` and wait for data, e.g. by registering a callback via `lo_server_add_method`. The client creates an address with `lo_address_new_with_proto` and uses it for `lo_send`, in which case a TCP connection is established, if not already set up.